# Django request.user become AnonymousUser after redirect

Tags: django, authentication, redirect

The problem here is that request.user always turn to AnonymousUser after redirect. 
I'm writing my own login method and authentication backend because I'm not using password for login. 
Here's my code.

```
#app/view.py
def login(request):
    template = 'index.html'
    if request.method == "POST":
        userId = request.POST.get('userId', '')
        displayName = request.POST.get('displayName', '')
        user = auth.authenticate(userId=userId, displayName=displayName)

        if user.is_authenticated:
            auth.login(request, user)
            return redirect('home') ##### if change to "render(request, template, locals())", will see request.user as logged in user #####
        else:
            return render(request, template, locals())
    else:
        return HttpResponse('')

    def home(request):
        template = 'index.html'
        user = request.user
        return render(request, template, locals())
```

I'm checking whether the request.user is logged in by javascript. If not, use a post function to /login/ URI. The liff.getProfile() is my third party javascript function to get userId and displayName from profile.

```
#html.javascript
DjangoLogin="{{request.user}}";
      if (DjangoLogin=="AnonymousUser"){
        liff.getProfile().then(function(profile) {
            userId = profile.userId;
            displayName = profile.displayName;
            post('/login/',{ 'userId': userId, 'displayName': displayName, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'});
          });
```

Comment: does your own `login` function save the logged in user in `session`?

Comment: I guess not. That's what I suspected. What you see is my whole login function. But I can't find related post or information. How do I do that?